# Why inner class called in python

Tags: python, function, scope, inner-classes

I have function where I declare class

```
>>> def a():
...     class A:
...         print "a"
...
```

When I call function, why it print `a`?

```
>>> a()
a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print "a"` is executed when the class `A`(not the instance of `A`) is created, and `a()` is creating the class.

Generally, it's useful for setting class variables and such.

Answer (score 5):

Because that's what you told it to do. There is nothing special about code written in a `class` block other than assignments will become attributes and normal functions defined within will be converted to methods. All other code just... executes.

Answer (score 2):

`print "a"` is executed when the class is defined - which happens when you call the function.